# How is a page made invalid in global page replacement?

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system, ram, page-tables

Let us say there are two processes A and B. B needs to insert a new frame in its page table. as there are no frames free, we have to swap out one frame and bring in B's frame from disk. Suppose the operating system follows global page replacement scheme and picks up a frame in which we have A's data. Now, to swap this frame out we need to change in A's page table that corresponding frame is invalid. To do that in general.we need to know which process's data is there in a particular frame in the memory so that we can go to it's page table and alter the bit to invalid. How is this acchieved? Does each frame in the memory also store process id of the corresponding process whose data it is having?

Comment: a physical memory frame isn't directly associated with a process id. As >1 process can share the same physical memory frame in its virtual address space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page Table is just the facility required by the processor hardware. On top of that, the OS is maintaining its own databases in memory keeping track of each physical page frame. For example, in Windows, there is a  Page Frame Database (PFN) listing out the status of each physical page like Valid, Standby, Modified, Free, etc. And for describing the subset of virtual pages residing in physical memory, there is a Working Set List.

For Windows, if you need to know more about the details of memory management, I suggest this book [http://www.amazon.com/Windows-Internals-Part-Developer-Reference/dp/0735665877/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1463848711&sr=8-3&keywords=windows+internals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735665877)